# NetBeans: How to add library from Maven repo for non-maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

For a plain "Java application" project, how can I add a dependency or library from Maven? If I right click on "Libraries" in the projects pane, it only allows me to add local libraries. But if my project is a Maven Java Application, then there's the "Dependencies" node in the projects pane, and from there I can right click and choose "Add dependency...".

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can either download the library manually e.g. from http://search.maven.org (don't forget the transitive dependencies as well!). Or if you're using Ant (the default project type in NetBeans): consider to use [Ant Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm fairly new to Java. Could you explain how using Ant may solve my problem here? Does NetBeans has better builtin support for Ant, or is it that I'll add libraries through Ant's command line utility?

Comment: If you're talking about "plain 'Java application' project" in NetBeans, this most likely means you're already have an Ant project, since NetBeans manages projects with Ant by default. And since you're already using Ant, I'm suggesting to use Ant Ivy to manage your dependencies.

Comment: That said, I recommend to get familiar with Maven (if you're not already) and prefer Maven over Ant. NetBeans has a good Maven support as well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to build a Maven style project before NetBeans can use its built in Maven plugin - to help you with dependencies.

See http://maven.apache.org/

Install Maven per the instructions exactly. Then you can generate a new Maven style project on the command line with

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

and import the generated project into NetBeans.